# Rails / Devise customize the create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I generate a special code which is unique to each user and generated on registration/create. I want to store it in the DB on create.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

  def create
    # insert special code into instance and ensure that code is unique in database
    super # continue to devise registration to CREATE user
  end

  protected
  def special_code
    ( (0...8).map { char = (65 + rand(26)).chr; }[0..rand(2...4)] << rand(1..9) ).join.downcase
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:name, :gender, :birthday]
  end
end
```

As you can see from my code, I added :name, :gender, :birthday columns (this works fine). I just don't know how to get the `special_code` into the record. Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to modify the create method. First find what the user is assigned to in create, (probably resource) and then assign the special code to it

```
  def create
    # insert special code into instance and ensure that code is unique in database
    super # continue to devise registration to CREATE user
    resource.update special_code: special_code # may want to check model is still valid at this point and handle errors if not
  end
```

also in routes you will need to tell it to use this controller

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'users/registrations' }
```

Comment: Yep this works. :) But was trying to avoid 2 db queries. How can this be done as 1? Thanks

Comment: Easiest way would be to copy over all of the create method and add it in there. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

Actually by the looks of it you can add the special_code to sign_up_params and it will automatically include it. This would involve overriding that method with 

`protected
  def sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_up).merge(special_code: special_code)
  end`

Comment: Yes it is easy! Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

I did it the following way (adjusting my own code to your situation):

**app/controllers/concerns/user_resource.rb**

```
module UserResource
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include Resource

  included do
    def resource_name
      :user
    end

    def resource
      if user_signed_in?
        current_user
      else
        @resource || User.new
      end
    end

    def build_resource(hash=nil)
      custom_params = hash.present? ? hash : {}
      custom_params[:special_code] = special_code
      self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(custom_params || {}, session)
    end

    def devise_mapping
      @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
    end

    helper_method :resource_name
    helper_method :resource
    helper_method :devise_mapping

    protected

    def special_code
      ( (0...8).map { char = (65 + rand(26)).chr; }[0..rand(2...4)] << rand(1..9) ).join.downcase
    end
  end
end
```

Your special code might belong into the UserResource class.

**app/controllers/concerns/resource.rb**

```
module Resource
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action { |c| c.resource}

    def resource_name
      raise NotImplementedError
    end

    def resource
      raise NotImplementedError
    end

    def devise_mapping
      raise NotImplementedError
    end
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  include UserResource

  def create
    resource = build_resource(sign_up_params)
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = "Sorry, we could not save you in our database. Please contact an adminstrator. #{resource.inspect}"
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

end
```

The routes should look like this. It seems you've already done that.

**app/config/routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {
  registrations: 'users/registrations'
}
```

Because the code did not work when I attempted to use a shorter solution, I had to copy [some code from the original Devise module](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb). Don't ask me why my previous code didn't work, it was really weird and kind of hard to fix.